# Embed google analytics stats in your site?

Tags: php, yii, google-analytics

I would like to show the actual statistics for both hourly and daily hits in the "stats" section of my site.

1. Is there a way to integrate this?
2. Can I also somehow integrate the "real time stats" showing the current active users on the site?
3. What about theming this to fit with my other stat charts?

Note: I don't mind if it's just iframes being displayed, but I can't find what to look for to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
$service = Yii::app()->JGoogleAPI->getService('Analytics');

$optParams = array(
 'metrics' => 'ga:visits',
 'max-results' => '1'
);

$gaData = 
  $service->data_ga->get( 
    'ga:66955412',
    $back,
    $back,
    'ga:visits',
    $optParams
  );

print $gaData->rows[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all information here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database or a file to save all the page visits and count the number of rows. See a live [example](http://serve-licson.net23.net/stats.php). I implanted this.

Comment: For online users, you can log the session ID and the current time stamp of each user, then check the current session ID exists in the table and the difference between the current time and the logged time. If the time difference excceed a limit, then we assumed the user is offline and delete the record. By counting the rows of the table you get the online user.